# Error al reparar tablas

Tags: phpmyadmin

Tengo una bd con 80 tablas, luego de seleccionar "reparar la tabla" en la mayoría de ellas aparece el mensaje "El manipulador de la tabla no permite soporte para...".
He buscado en internet y, aunque no lo crean, no he conseguido información que me ayude.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: Que manejador de base de datos usa?
Puede escribir exactamente el error.

Comment: Disculpa, pensé que colocando la etiqueta era suficiente. Estoy usando phpMyAdmin y el error que me da es el que coloqué inicialmente: "El manipulador de la tabla no permite soporte para..."